# How to properly create an instance of AnnotatedControllerConfigurer

Tags: spring-graphql

I'm trying to define a configuration to create an ExecutionGraphQlService to wire into an existing application as a proof of concept, but I'm a bit confused about how to create an instance of a AnnotatedControllerConfigurer. Here is what I currently have settled upon.

```
AnnotatedControllerConfigurer annotatedControllerConfigurer = new AnnotatedControllerConfigurer();

annotatedControllerConfigurer.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
annotatedControllerConfigurer.afterPropertiesSet();
annotatedControllerConfigurer.configure(runtimeWiringBuilder);
```

AnnotatedControllerConfigurer implements ApplicationContextAware, InitializingBean so it seems to expect to be initialized as a bean, but attempts to autowire an instance of it fail due to `Could not autowire. No beans of 'AnnotatedControllerConfigurer' type found.`
I've attempted constructor injection `public ExecutionGraphQlService defaultExecutionGraphQlService(AnnotatedControllerConfigurer annotatedControllerConfigurer)` as well as manual instantiation `autowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(annotatedControllerConfigurer)` (which should be basically the same thing).

It seems like this class is not a bean, but expects to be managed by Spring's bean lifecycle? Is my approach the expected approach?

Comment: Is this a Spring Boot application? How are you wiring in the existing application? I guess you're registering data fetchers? Are you schema resources located in `src/main/resources/graphql/` as expected by Spring Boot?

Comment: This is not a spring boot application. I'm creating an instance of the ExecutionGraphQlService to wire into our existing application elsewhere (currently just using a plain controller class, this is a barebones POC). Schema resources aren't an issue; I've configured those to be found. After posting this I got the project working, but it still seems odd how this entity is managed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AnnotatedControllerConfigurer` type is meant to be a bean in the Spring container, and is using the bean lifecycle to setup the infrastructure.

Creating it as a bean (given other pieces are contributed as beans as well). The runtime wiring should be configured on the `GraphQlSource` directly.

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
class GraphQlConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public AnnotatedControllerConfigurer annotatedControllerConfigurer() {
    return new AnnotatedControllerConfigurer();
  }

}
```